# Jenkins | parallel | problem to run class instances

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to run stages from 2 class instances with parallel but i'm getting this error: "roovy.lang.MissingFieldException: No such field" from one of them, but if i'm running one of them it ok.

the groovy classes are in src folder and i'm using them with library and creating an instance for each of them.

this is my parallel code from the jenkins file:

```
def parallelStagesMap = pipelineDailyStages.collectEntries {
            def name = it.getSetupname()
            echo "name: " + name
            ["${name}" : it.generateStage(name)]
          }
```

---

these are the classes:
package stages

```
class DSmall extends DStages implements Serializable{

  def local_mx
  def local_g
  def local_agent

  DamSmall(environment, local_setupname, local_rp_launch_id, local_ssbuild, local_catagry, local_runners, local_artifactstodownload, local_resourcepool, local_mngnetwork, local_datastore, local_vmfolder, local_dcap_deploy, local_remotedebugport, local_m, local_g, local_agentoracle){
    super(environment, local_setupname, local_rp_launch_id, local_ssbuild, local_catagry, local_runners, local_artifactstodownload, local_resourcepool, local_mngnetwork, local_datastore, local_vmfolder, local_deploy, local_remotedebugport)

    this.local_m = local_m
    this.local_g = local_g
    this.local_agent = local_agent
  }


  def generateStage(a){
    return {
        this.environment.stage("stage: ${a}") {
                this.environment.echo "This is da."
        }
    }
  }
}

class DaSmall extends DStages implements Serializable{

  def local_m
  def local_agent
  def local_oracletemplate
  def local_oracle_start_db

  DasSmall(environment, local_setupname, local_rp_launch_id, local_ssbuild, local_catagry, local_runners, local_artifactstodownload, local_resourcepool, local_mngnetwork, local_datastore, local_vmfolder, local_dcap_deploy, local_remotedebugport, local_mxs, local_agent, local_oracletemplate, local_oracle_start_db){
    super(environment, local_setupname, local_rp_launch_id, local_ssbuild, local_catagry, local_runners, local_artifactstodownload, local_resourcepool, local_mngnetwork, local_datastore, local_vmfolder, local_deploy, local_remotedebugport)

    this.local_mxs = local_mxs
    this.local_agentoracle = local_agentoracle
    this.local_oracletemplate = local_oracletemplate
    this.local_oracle_start_db = local_oracle_start_db
  }


  def generateStage(a){
    return {
        this.environment.stage("stage: ${a}") {
                this.environment.echo "This is da."
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: groovy.lang.MissingFieldException: No such field: environment for class: stages.DaSmall

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution, I created the class instances from another groovy file that sits in vars folder(not from the jenkins file)